# What attacked my peach tree?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, trees, pest-control

[image: From top there are some white bugs, from bottom there are some other]
Help me please! I have to get rid of these!

Comment: I Guess Its this http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/aphid/green_peach_aphid.htm. please feel free to add more information.

Comment: Please provide your location, time of year you took the photo, species/cultivar of peach tree (if known) and an approximate size for the pests. Thanks.

Comment: I am happy that i was right ať least with that fact that it is aphid. 

Comment: @L.Diago yeah, nice call! Glad you added the guess as a comment. It helped me form the 2nd half of my answer :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are definitely some sort of [aphid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphid) (small sap-sucking [true bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemiptera) in the superfamily Aphidoidea).

Based on the coloration and shape of the pest and the host plant, my best guess is that you're looking at [***Hyalopterus pruni***](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/r5300711.html) (or the **Mealy Plum Aphid**).

- Note: the scientific name of this species has [changed at least 21 times!](http://hilgardia.ucanr.edu/Abstract/?a=hilg.v10n07p167)

[image: Picture]

<sup>Photo by [Jack Kelly Clark](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/H/I-HO-HPRU-CO.002.html)</sup>

- Looks like [this person](https://bugguide.net/node/view/1246214) also found this species of aphids on a black cherry tree if you want to see more picture.

#### Description:

> Wingless adult aphids are pale green with three dark green longitudinal stripes on their backs. Their bodies are covered with a white, mealy wax. [[source](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/r5300711.html)].

#### Host Plants:

Typically trees in the **[*Prunus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus) genus**: cherries, plums, almonds, apricots, nectarines, and -- you guessed it --  **peaches**. [[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyalopterus_pruni)].

#### Damage:

Plant can become stunted from high numbers of aphids, but the primary concern is the development of mold that grows on the aphid's [honeydew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeydew_(secretion)). [[source](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/r5300711.html)].

#### Management:

See this [University of California Agriculture and Natural Resources site](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/r5300711.html) for **management suggestions**.

Suggestions:

- *Biological*: lady beetles, lacewings, or soldier flies
- *Organic*: biological control + sprays of neem oil
- *Pesticides* (typically not needed): Phosmet, Diazinon, and others in the fall; neem oil, flonicamid and others in the spring.

#### Final Notes:

Just because an aphid shares a name with an individual plant (e.g., the [green peach aphid](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/veg/aphid/green_peach_aphid.htm) mentioned in the comments) doesn't mean that the species is limited to just that plant or that any aphid found on said host is that species. Many aphids feed on a wide range of host plants, so limiting your host to an individual species doesn't necessarily rule out a wide range of pests. However, it is not uncommon for an aphid species to stick to a single genus, narrow set of genera, or narrow set of families of host plants.